# When would one use the word "participance" in place of "participation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

The Oxford English Dictionary includes three words that all appear to have the same meaning: *[participation](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138245?redirectedFrom=participation#eid)*, *[participance](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138242?redirectedFrom=participance#eid31572450)*, and *[participancy](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138242?redirectedFrom=participancy#eid31572449)*. I'm curious if there is a difference between the three.

> **participation** *n*. The process or fact of sharing in an action, sentiment, etc.; (now esp.) active involvement in a matter or event, esp. one in which the outcome directly affects those taking part. Frequently with in.
>
> **parˈticipance** *n*. *rare* = *participancy* *n*.
>
> **parˈticipancy**  *n*. the fact or quality of participating in something.

The word "participation" is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=participancy%2Cparticipation%2C%20participatance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparticipancy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparticipation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cparticipancy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparticipation%3B%2Cc0) than the latter two. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/208035/102244) lays out a distinction between *participation* and *participancy*, but I am still unclear if *participance* can be differentiated between *participation*.

What is the difference between the word "participation" and the word "participance"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that since *participance* is used less commonly, it sounds a bit formal, and one expects to hear it in contexts such as politics, law, etc.

Another difference, in my view, is in the meanings of the suffixes "-tion" and "-ance (-ence)":

"-tion" is broader in sense, indicating *state, condition, action, process*, or *result*

while "-ence", having a more limited signification, only means "*the act of ____*" and is bare of any other possible connotations.

One such distinction can be seen here:
https://wikidiff.com/continuance/continuation

On the meaning of "–ance" and "-ence":
https://www.newtimes.co.rw/section/read/231328